# How to select column value after first comma using sql query

Tags: sql

I am trying to fetch the column value after first comma using sql query. I have written the query but It is not optimized.
I want the data in output after the first comma in Address field.

**Data**

```
ID  Address
1   Add1,Add2,Add3
2   Add1,Add2
```

**Expected  Output**

```
ID  Address
1   Add2,Add3
2   Add2
```

**Query**

```
select right(Address, len(Address) - charindex(',', reverse(Address)))
```

Can anyone help to write the optimized query for above table and output.

Comment: One quick option is STUFF()  ...  stuff(Address,1,charindex(',',Address),'')

Comment: The only incorrect part of what you're doing is `charindex(',', reverse(Address))` should just be `charindex(',', Address)` but other than that it looks the same as if you were to write a substring (e.g. `SUBSTRING(Address, CHARINDEX(',' Address)+1, LEN(Address))`)

Comment: @ZLK I am using the RIGHT function bcz of that Using reverse function

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: See the function `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just divide the address after first comma you can use the below query.

```
SELECT ID,SUBSTRING(Address , CHARINDEX(',' , Address) + 1 , LEN(Address)) FROM Data;
```

If you want to divide it based on the number of addresses then this query is more suitable

```
WITH DivideName 
AS 
( 
SELECT ID,name,(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Address)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Address,1,CHARINDEX(',',Address)-1) ELSE Address END) part, (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Address)!=0 THEN SUBSTRING(Address,CHARINDEX(',',Address)+1,LEN(Address)) ELSE Address END) Rempart, 1 countno 
FROM author
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID,Address,(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Rempart)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Rempart,1,CHARINDEX(',',Rempart)-1) ELSE Rempart END) part, (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Rempart)!=0 THEN SUBSTRING(Rempart,CHARINDEX(',',Rempart)+1,LEN(Rempart)) ELSE Rempart END) Rempart, countno + 1 FROM DivideName WHERE countno<(LEN(Address)-LEN(REPLACE(Address,',',''))+1) 
) 
SELECT Address, part Word, countno WordNo FROM DivideName ORDER BY ID,countno
```